# Alternative way to compute modular inverse

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse

I am trying to compute the inverse of $35 \mod 7344$. Using the extended Euclidean algorithm I get that $1=1259\cdot 35-6\cdot 7344$ and therefore $1259\cdot 35 =1 \mod 7344$.

Now I want to use a different method to calculate the inverse. I know that $7344=2^4\cdot 3^2 \cdot 51$. Let's name $e=35$ and $d$ its inverse (because this is actually an RSA problem). I know that
$$e=3\mod 2^3 \quad, \quad e=-1\mod 3^2 \quad , \quad e=35\mod51$$
And these equations give us the following conditions:
$$d=3\mod 2^3 \quad, \quad d=-1\mod 3^2 \quad , \quad d=35\mod51$$
Therefore I must be able to take $d=35$ as the inverse. However this is clearly not true. Why is this not working?

**Edit** As Peter pointed out in the comments, I missed a factor of $2$, and  $51$ is not coprime with $3$ and therefore I cannot use the chinese reminder theorem this way

Comment: To apply the chinese remainder theorem (what you apparently want to do) , you need pairwise coprime moduli. If you take $2^4,3^3$ and $17$, it will work. Also you missed a factor $2$

Comment: @Peter My bad, I don't know why I was absolutely sure that $51$ is a prime number

Comment: Your answer is correct mod the lcm of your moduli, which is $\,{\rm lcm}(2^3,3^2,51) = 1224,\,$ i.e. $\,d = 1259\equiv \color{#0a0}{35\pmod{1224}}$. But you need $d$ mod $\,\color{#c00}6*1224 = 7344$
so we can go further: $\bmod 7344\!:\ 1 \equiv 35d\equiv 35(\color{#0a0}{35+1224k})\equiv 1225-1224k\iff 1224k\equiv 1224\iff\,$ $\color{#0a0}{k\equiv 1}\pmod{6}\iff d\equiv 1259\pmod{7344}\ \ $